# Is there a way to guarantee resize event fires AFTER orientationchange event (jQuery Mobile, JavaScript)?

Tags: iphone, events, jquery-mobile, resize, orientation

I'm having an issue with iOS, specifically the iPhone, where my jQuery Mobile web app is firing a window resize event BEFORE jQuery Mobile's orientationchange event.  I have not seen this occur on Android in my testing, at this point (meaning, it could spring up later).  Is there a way I can guarantee the resize event fires AFTER the orientationchange event, perhaps utilizing window.orientation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news and bad news.  The bad news is, no, you can't guarantee it.  This bugs have been around since the beginning and still have not been fully worked out.  I would not expect them to be any time soon, nor would I expect that other platform competitors will implement theirs correctly as they rush to get to market at reduced overhead.

The good news is, you probably don't even need the javascript events.  There's a pretty good chance you can accomplish all you're looking to do with CSS Media Queries and do it more reliably.

```
/* Regular mobile styles */
.logo-large{
    background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:290px;
    height:65px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    border:none;
}



/* Horizontal */
@media all and (min-width: 480px){
    /* put your horizontal stylings here */
}

/* HD / Retina */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {
    .logo-large{
        background-image:url(../images/logoHD.png);background-size:290px 65px;
    }
}


/* iPad */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is slightly off topic; I want the content to have a width equal to that of the layout viewport for both portrait and landscape, not to mention the device can change orientation after the page loads, and it should work for iPhone, and all versions (1.x, 2.x, 4.x) and resolutions for Android phones. So, how can I replicate that using CSS Media Queries? Will your example above permit this dynamic?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what this does.  The section labeled as horizontal will kick into effect the moment they turn their phone and the rules will be immediately applied without you having to execute any javascript.  In fact, this way would work even if javascript was turned off.  This is the beginnings of what is known as Responsive Web Design.

So, in the section label as horizontal, just put in the css rule overrides that you want to take effect if they turn their phone.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is the min-width in the media query reporting the device width (i.e. Retina Display, 960) or the viewport width (i.e. Retina Display, 480)?  The problem is there are all different versions of android resolutions and, during my testing across different versions and resolutions, the landscape width (i.e. clientWidth) is not consistent.  For example, there are android devices in the wild whose resolutions are 240x320, 240x400, and 240x432.  My other thought is querying for specific widths may require maintenance as new devices and resolutions are released. Thank you so much.

Comment: True, thus making the case for fluid layouts.  I would just set your content's width to be 100% with maybe a margin of 5px left and right and just let the devices reflow the content as needed. Don't think in terms of fixed widths.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I did just that.  If you allow the user to scale, the visual and layout viewports are the same.  I reported the fix here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638622/how-do-i-maintain-fixed-width-for-layout-viewport-in-android-iphone-with-user/9743916#9743916), which is related to my original question.  But I won't give up on using CSS media queries, since this is the preferred method of supporting myriad different platforms and devices.  Thank you, again, for your help.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout in order to wait for the orientationchange event

IT WORKS

```
   $(window).bind('resize', function() { setTimeout( function() { messageToNativeApp('screen_resized'); }, 500); });
```