# How do I get the new dimensions of an element *after* it resizes due to a screen orientation change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a mobile web app, and in my page I have a `div` element with its width set to 100%.

I need to set the height of this `div` so that the height is correct for a set aspect ratio.  So for example, if the screen was sized to 300 pixels wide and the ratio was 3:2, my script should grab the width of the `div` (which at this point should be 300px) and set the height to 200px.

On first load, this works perfectly. However, if I rotate the screen of my phone to landscape, the width of the `div` obviously changes, so I need to reset its height in order  to keep the correct ratio.

My problem is that I can't find an event which fires *after* the elements are resized. There is an `orientationchange` event built into jQuery Mobile, which helpfully fires when the screen is rotated from portrait to landscape and vice-versa:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function (e) {

    // Correctly alerts 'landscape' or 'portrait' when orientation is changed
    alert(e.orientation); 

    // Set height of div
    var div = $('#div');
    var width = div.width();

    // Shows the *old* width, i.e the div's width before the rotation
    alert(width);

    // Set the height of the div (wrongly, because width is incorrect at this stage)
    div.css({ height: Math.ceil(width / ratio) });

});
```

But this event seems to fire *before* any of the elements in the page have resized to fit the new layout, which means (as mentioned in the comments) I can only get the pre-rotation width of the `div`, which is not what I need.

Does anyone know how I can get the `div`'s new width, *after* things have resized themselves?

Comment: Have you tried the `resize` event (on `$(window)`)?

Comment: Is the change pretty instantaneous after the orientationchange function is called? If there isn't a method for orientationchange complete or something along those lines, you could always use a setTimeout to run a function after xxx milliseconds. There may be a *slight* delay, but probably not super noticeable.

Comment: @ori Yes, I have tried the `resize` event—it fires at pretty much exactly the same time (and in fact I think `orientationchange` uses it as a fallback for browsers that don't natively support the orientation event).

Comment: @Kory It's looking more and more like a timed function might be the way to go. I was just hoping for something a little 'tidier'!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823971/is-there-a-way-to-guarantee-resize-event-fires-after-orientationchange-event-jq/9824737#9824737

Comment: @sgliser Also looks interesting, I'll try your technique later too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few methods for you to try:

**(1)** Set a timeout inside your `orientationchange` event handler so the DOM can update itself and the browser can draw all the changes before you poll for the new dimension:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function (e) { 
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Get height of div
        var div   = $('#div'),
            width = div.width();

        // Set the height of the div
        div.css({ height: Math.ceil(width / ratio) });
    }, 500);
});
```

It won't make too big of a difference but note that `Math.ceil` takes a lot longer to complete (relatively) than `Math.floor` since the latter only has to drop everything after the decimal point. I generally just pass the browser the un-touched float number and let it round where it wants to.

**(2)** Use the `window.resize` event instead to see if that updated fast enough for you:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function (e) { 
    // Get height of div
    var div   = $('#div'),
        width = div.width();

    // Set the height of the div
    div.css({ height: Math.ceil(width / ratio) });
});
```

On a mobile device this will fire when the orientation changes since the size of the browser view-port will also change.

**(3)** If you are updating the size of this `<div>` element because it holds an image, just apply some CSS to the image to make it always be full-width and the correct aspect ratio:

```
.my-image-class {
    width  : 100%;
    height : auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried #2 (no luck, see my comment on the question), but will take a look at your other suggestions tomorrow!

Comment: @MarkBell I have used the first suggestion successfully many times before. However I would recommend using the third solution if you can since it's the most simple and will create the least CPU overhead.

Comment: I ended up using a combination of #1 and #3, due to some weird behaviour exhibited by a plugin I was using. Thanks though, works well now!