# Making DIV in an IFRAME scrollable

Tags: ipad, html, mobile, iframe, scrollable

Page A has an `iframe` (that loads Page B). That Page B has a `div#OutputDiv`. My goal is to make that `div` in that `iframe` scrollable.

> **SOLUTION (CREDIT TO STEVE!):**
>
> 1. Include `overflow: auto` for that `div`. However you must specify `height` too. Simply give any fixed value. eg `height: 0`.
> 2. Use a javascript function to make the div's `height` always same as the window's, even after window resize. `height` is now not fixed.
>
> **Code:**

```
#outputDiv {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-right: 1em;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden; (optional)
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; (enable smooth scrolling on mobile)
    height: 0; (omit-able)
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#outputDiv").css("height",0).css("height",$(this).height());
});
$(window).trigger("resize");
```

*TL;DR Full story*

**Page A.html** - has an `iframe` to load **Page B**. When on Page A, that `div#OutputDiv` in that `iframe` must be scrollable. Works fine on PC but not scrollable on iPad/Android. Page structure:

**Page B.php** - Left half `div#OutputDiv`, right half `div#map-canvas` containing Google Maps.

*(Sidenote: I think the `#map-canvas` CSS is pretty unchangeable, for example changing something may cause the Maps to extend height beyond browser height, which is not what I want.)*

**Page A.html**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #title-banner {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #real-time-alert {
        margin-top: 155px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .tab-content {
        border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .nav-tabs {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #panel {
        position: fixed;
        top: 120px;
        right: 10px;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 350px;
    }

    iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<body>
<div id="title-banner" class="well"><h1>Real-time incident updates</h1></div>
<div id="real-time-alert">
    DEMO:<br>
    <a id="demolink" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold;">22/11/2013, 0.32.18AM: 3.128268, 101.650656<br></a>
</div>

<div id="panel">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#map">Map</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#message">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="map"><iframe seamless name="map-report"></iframe></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="message"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Page B.php**
*for div#map-canvas, I had to do the code below, or else when I hover on the page, div#OutputDiv will disappear. This may be not important.

> ```
> $("*").hover(function(){
>      $("#map-canvas").css("position","fixed"); });
> ```

```
<style>
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 50%;
        }
        #content-pane {
            float:left;
            width:48%;
            padding-left: 2%;
        }
        #outputDiv {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: Arial;
            margin-right: 1em;
        }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="content-pane">
        <div class='well well-small' id="inputs" style="margin: 1em 1em 0 0">
            <b>TESTING ONLY</b> <br>
            <label for="originLat">Incident Site: </label><input type="text" id="originLat" style="width:6em;" />
            <input type="text" id="originLng" style="width:6em;" />
            <button type="button">Calculate distances</button>
            </br>eg. 3.126547,101.657825
        </div>
        <div id="outputDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="position: fixed; right: 1px;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any overflow controls specified in the CSS (apologies if I missed them).

Have you tried:

```
div#OutputDiv { overflow: auto; height: 200px; }
```

The height is just for testing purposes - but you could use Javascript to get the actual height and apply it using either raw javascript or jQuery.

A good example (including how to detect orientation changes if device goes portrait to landscape or similar) can be found on:

[How do I get the new dimensions of an element *after* it resizes due to a screen orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929368/how-do-i-get-the-new-dimensions-of-an-element-after-it-resizes-due-to-a-screen)

Comment: I have tried this too, but if i was not mistaken, it lengthens Page B so all contents fit instead of making contents inside iframe scrollable without changing iframe size... and it makes the page very long because of big Google Maps:
<div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
  <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%">
</div>

Comment: Sorry I missed a key point that as well as overflow: auto you would need to specify a fixed height. You could get this from Javascript ultimately to be the available height of the iframe, but for the moment if you specify a height of say 200px - does it make the div scrollable? Responding on my phone currently - will try myself when I get back to my desk later...

Comment: It works Steve! can you post in a new answer so I can give you a tick?? and can you include the javascript code that get the height everytime when the browser changes? 'cause one might size window or rotate the mobile device?
Thank you Steve, I din expect to solve!

Comment: Great - glad it worked out - I've updated my answer above with the full solution, and a link to another Stack Overflow thread which covers getting the height as the device orientation changes etc. Hope this all works neatly for you.

Comment: Thanks Steve! Jasper's solution didn't work well for me as my case is a lil different.
Somehow because of the Google Maps over there, if initial height in CSS="`some value`", when the screen (esp mobile) resizes to <`some value`, some area in the bottom cannot be reached when scroll.

So (and if what I said is hard to understand), always reset height=0 before resizing to desired value, like below:
`$(window).resize(function(){         $("#outputDiv").css("height",0).css("height",$(this).height()); }); //or use .height();
$(window).trigger("resize"); //when content first loaded;`